# How do I handle 404 errors from Android Google Quick Search Box?

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics, android

The San Francisco Municipal Transportation Agency has a Drupal website, example.com.

In Google Analytics, I'm noticing a lot of strange 404 errors that are coming from android-app://com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox

In a few cases, I can pin them down as "legitimate" 404s that refer to an URL on our site that has gone away or been changed, in which case I can safely say "our bad" and add appropriate redirects.

But, in many cases, the 404s contain spaces or misspellings that never, so far as I can tell, existed as or in URLs on our website. If Google Quick Search Box is actually doing a search, it seems like it is passing the misspelling through to our website.

For instance, I see:

/404.html?page=/twimpeak?utm_source=Legacy&from=android-app://com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox

Which implies someone typed https://www.example.com/twimpeak into the Google Quick Search Box and it did a passthrough. There would be no reason for them to put in Twimpeak (as a search term, without a domain) and have Google return https://www.example.com/twimpeak as a result.

Where does this Google Quick Search Box reside and can someone confirm this is the behavior? Is there anything I can do about this so that the visitor gets useful information as opposed to a 404 Not Found?